# chef-jira cookbook - vagrant issues

Tags: tomcat, vagrant, chef-infra, jira

Using the cookbook from https://github.com/bflad/chef-jira
Using the Vagrantfile from the cookbook

Used the command:

```
vagrant up ubuntu1204 > c:\temp\chef-jira.log
```

The first error in the log file:

```
==> ubuntu1204: [2014-08-30T14:23:41+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> ubuntu1204: [2014-08-30T14:23:41+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> ubuntu1204: [2014-08-30T14:23:41+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> ubuntu1204: [2014-08-30T14:23:41+00:00] DEBUG: Chef::Exceptions::ResourceNotFound: resource template[/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/jira.xml] is configured to notify resource service[tomcat] with action restart, but service[tomcat] cannot be found in the resource collection. template[/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/jira.xml] is defined in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/jira/recipes/container_server_configuration.rb:8:in `from_file'
```

Any ideas how to resolve the error?

Thanks,
Liora

Comment: What is your runlist ? (better: could you insert your vagrantfile in the question, at least the add_recipe parts). Moreover, You may dump the whole chef output (which has the runlist at top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a resource in recipe A is dependent on a resource in recipe B, include the recipe B on top of your recipe A.